# TSX Input Value

Tags: reactjs, input, state, tsx

I am developing a web app using React.JS.

I would like the input to be a default value, but the input can't be uneditable.

I have tried :

```
let [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState<string>('Value of Input')
return (
    <div className = "App">
        <input value={inputValue}></input>
    </div>
```

The problem with this is that i can't edit the input.

Comment: Well you need to add an `onChange` handler to update the state as they type in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need onChange on that input, and you can change state with that onChange event

```
const handleOnChange = (event) => {
    setInputValue(event.target.value);
  };
```

and you can add h1 to see what's inside the state

```
<h1>this is what inputValue state content: {inputValue}</h1>
```

and the whole code will look like this

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("Value of Input");

  const handleOnChange = (event) => {
    setInputValue(event.target.value);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>this is the content of inputValue state: {inputValue}</h1>
      <input onChange={(event) => handleOnChange(event)}></input>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input value={inputValue} onChange={(e) => setInputValue(e.target.value)}></input>
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.